# Displaying 2D array with ngfor

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am pulling some message data from firebase database and trying to display them as a list  on page using `ngfor`.
The problem is this is structure of the data coming from db is 2 d array
[image]

code below explains the structure:

```
this.msg=messages[0][3]; //first users 3rd message content.(0 is key of messagecontent)
      this.msg=messages[0][3].message //first users 3rd message contents message.actual message i want to display.
```

msg is an observable.

so how do i write a proper ngfor for this data ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 using nested ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767542/angular-2-using-nested-ngfor)

Answer (score 3):

Well, in the simplest way you can :)

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages | async">
  <div *ngFor="let prop of message">
    <!-- You should have everything here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 0th member of message content is key

Comment: Sorry, what ? You asked for a way to double loop on it. Could you state your current need instead ?

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/2gneWWsjRvq7nbsDFmTbgA.png   key causes error i guess https://image.prntscr.com/image/AX7VUBu4SVStwD62qSAaxQ.png

Comment: No, the async pipe causes an error. You told me messages was an Observable, but it seems it isn't. Delete the second `| async`, if it still doesn't work, delete the first too.

Comment: nothing comes up if i remove both | async.if i remove one error again.

Comment: You don't need `| async` at all since `messages` isn't an `Observable`, `this.msg` is (according to OP). Make sure you put some html inside so you actually see something on the screen.

Comment: the second async isnt necessary, as only mssages is supposed to be an obs