# *Ngfor over multidimensional array in different select-boxes

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array

I have problems with irating over subarrays/object.

The source is data like this (from a mongodb)

```
[{"_id":"5a7f49972df35835b8c6650a","manufacterer":"ManufactererA","name":"M1000","cpus":[{"name":"CPU0","desc":"test"},{"name":"CPU1","desc":"test1"},{"name":"CPU2","desc":"test2"},{"name":"CPU3","desc":"test3"}]},{"_id":"5a8001332df35841841f6a7b","manufacterer":"ManufactererA","name":"M2000"}]
```

Here is model server:

```
export class Server {
  _id?: string;
  manufacterer?: string;
  model?: string;
  cpus?: any;
}
```

and they get defined :

```
  server = new Server();
  servers: Server[] = [];
  manufacterers = [];
```

The manufacterer got selected by a previous select-box without any errors.

In the following select-box the user selects the model.

```
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="manufactererValue">
        <mat-select placeholder="Model" name="model" [(ngModel)]="model">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let server of servers" [value]="server">
            {{server.name}}
          </mat-option> 
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is working fine. Now I want to iterate again over the cpu-array in another select-box. I still did not understand the right way how to iterate over it. This is my not working code:

```
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="manufactererValue && model"> 
        <mat-select placeholder="Cpu" name="cpu" [(ngModel)]="cpus">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let cpu of model.cpus" [value]="cpu">
            {{cpu.name}} + {{cpu.desc}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Example: the user selects M1000 in the first select-box (model) and in next select-box should appear the corresponding cpus `"cpus":[{"name":"CPU0","desc":"test"},{"name":"CPU1","desc":"test1"},{"name":"CPU2","desc":"test2"},{"name":"CPU3","desc":"test3"}]` and so on...

Even [Angular 2 using nested ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767542/angular-2-using-nested-ngfor) doesnt help me

**The cpu select-box is still empty**

Comment: Hint: You will want to integrate an `[(ngModel)]="selectedServer"` to determine which cpus to display.

Comment: Can you give me a code example please?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48768465/9122537) answer it might help

Comment: Thanks, but is almost the same like I did, but it didnt helped me.

Comment: Have you tried putting your code inside ng-container tag and then write the loop inside the tag?

Comment: I marked the answer as good. Its important to use the previous ngModel as new array to iterate over it. Its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to bind a model to your `selected server` and then based on it you can know through which array you need to iterate inside to list all `CPUs`, so something like this will work:

```
 <mat-form-field *ngIf="manufactererValue">
    <mat-select placeholder="Model" name="model" [(ngModel)]="server">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let server of servers" [value]="server">
        {{server.model}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Then your other form field:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="manufactererValue && server">
    <mat-select placeholder="Model" name="cpu" [(ngModel)]="cpu">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let cpu of server.cpu" [value]="cpu">
        {{cpu}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

**EDIT:**

This is how your `server` and `cpu` should look like

```
let server: {_id?: string; manufacterer?: string; model?: string; cpu?: any[]};
let cpu: any;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt work. The select-box cpu is empty.

Comment: Do you have your `server` and `cpu` variable defined in your `controller` like this: `let server: any; let cpu: any;`

Comment: server is an instance of a mongoose model, so its defined. I defined cpu now, but it still doesnt show anything.

Comment: It seems like `mat-select` can't bind `objects` so you need to pass some kind of  `server identifier` which you will use in `controller` to retrieve unique `server` and then do `this.server = result_by_identifier`;

Comment: Its not possible to use the [(ngModel)]="server"? server is definded `server = new Server();` and `export class Server {
  _id?: string;
  manufacterer?: string;
  model?: string;
  cpu?: string;  
}
`

Comment: Can you check if the `server` variable is updated once you change the `server select`, after you've corrected the `server` and `cpu` variables inside the controller as per my edit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165003/discussion-between-piter-parker-and-nikola-gavric).