# How to show data from nested web service array (Angular 4)

Tags: json, angular, web-services, typescript, multidimensional-array

I made a project to pull data from web service API.
But the web service has nested arrays that needs to be displayed too, how can i access the data from nested JSON arrays?, what is the right way to write inside the HTML to get the data from the web service.
By the way when i fetch the first objects it shows correctly, only in the nested objects.

This is the response screenshot from Postman

[image: This is the response screenshot from Postman]

[This is the API link](https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/admin/grades/division?school_id=76)

[This is the link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vduzzk) of the project on Stackblitz

Click on sign in without user or password, then any school, then divisions.
divisions component is the one i'm asking about.

Comment: I think you're looking for nested [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor) directives. As long as you know the structure of the data, you can write an `*ngFor` in your template to handle the first array, and then one within that to handle the second-level array.

Comment: i did that in the project, have you looked inside it?
it's not working

Comment: Certainly can look at the project - which component should I look at?

Comment: division component

Comment: Yup, I'd follow what Boris is recommending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you have the data available.
Just use the dots to reach the data you need: response.data[0].grade[0].classes[1].grade_id

In the template you can do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let division of divisionList">
    <div *ngFor="let grade of division.grade">
        <div *ngFor="let class of grade.classes">
            <span>{{ class.grade_id }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your component you can start with this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="divisionList">
    <button name="American Primary"  
        *ngFor="let division of divisionList"
        class="choose-list arrow-onclick1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list1">
           {{division.name}}
         <i class="fa fa-arrow-right pull-right arrow-down-onclick1" 
            aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:12px"></i>
    </button>
    <a routerLink="/editaisdivision" 
        style="text-decoration: none;">
       <span class="fa fa-pencil pen-pen-pen" aria-hidden="true" 
             style="margin-left: 10px; color: #171b5e;"></span>
     </a>
</ng-container>
```

Note that you can't use two structural (with *) directives in one tag, hence the ng-container.

Comment: No, i tried that already, not showing the data of the grades array.

Comment: Cool! Getting to know your project better and better :D

Comment: No, i'm getting to know Angular itself better :p

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(JSON_STRING)` and you will get a JavaScript object that represents the data in the JSON.