# ngFor in angular with array of array

Tags: angular, typescript

1. List item:

```
jsonObject = [
    {
      place: 'place1',
      fatherDetails: [
        {name: 'place1_father1', adharId: 134567},
        {name: 'place1_father2', adharId: 124567},
      ],
      motherDetails: [
        {name: 'place1_mother1', adharId: 123456},
        {name: 'place1_mother2', adharId: 123457},
        {name: 'place1_mother3', adharId: 123467},
      ],
    },
    {
      place: 'place2',
      fatherDetails: [
        {name: 'place2_father1', adharId: 123567},
        {name: 'place2_father2', adharId: 12567},
      ],
      motherDetails: [
        {name: 'place2_mother1', adharId: 1234567},
        {name: 'place2_mother2', adharId: 1234567},
        {name: 'place2_mother3', adharId: 1234567},
      ],
    }
  ];
```

How do I loop all the `fatherDetails` objects in HTML with ngFor?
Basically, I require something like this:

```
<mat-option *ngFor = "let father of jsonObject">
   {{father.name}}
</mat-option>
```

But, this doesn't work. Because, it has to loop twice.

Comment: That's not Json

Comment: Why is it not JSON object?

Comment: @MaruthiEranki before you ask for something, please mention what you have tried, do you have done any research, and do you know how to use `ngFor`, if you your basic is not clear refer `https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives`.

Comment: I tried  and also mentioned what I've tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 using nested ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767542/angular-2-using-nested-ngfor)

Comment: Question is duplicate, answer is slightly different. Use ng-container as described in https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using Angular's ng-container.

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let object of jsonObject>
        <mat-option *ngFor = "let father of object.fatherDetails">
            {{father.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </ng-container
```

ng-container won't clutter your DOM with unnecessary divs and allows you to access that nested array.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me and I was looking for something like ng-container.

Answer (score 1):

Note You need to iterate the first loop and the second loop will be iterated inside the first loop's array of object.

```js
jsonObject = [{
    place: 'place1',
    fatherDetails: [{
        name: 'place1_father1',
        adharId: 134567
      },
      {
        name: 'place1_father2',
        adharId: 124567
      },
    ],
    motherDetails: [{
        name: 'place1_mother1',
        adharId: 123456
      },
      {
        name: 'place1_mother2',
        adharId: 123457
      },
      {
        name: 'place1_mother3',
        adharId: 123467
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    place: 'place2',
    fatherDetails: [{
        name: 'place2_father1',
        adharId: 123567
      },
      {
        name: 'place2_father2',
        adharId: 12567
      },
    ],
    motherDetails: [{
        name: 'place2_mother1',
        adharId: 1234567
      },
      {
        name: 'place2_mother2',
        adharId: 1234567
      },
      {
        name: 'place2_mother3',
        adharId: 1234567
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let object of jsonObject;let i = index;">
  <td>{{i}}</td>
  <td * ngFor="let o of object.motherDetails">{{o}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just extract fatherDetails from all items, flat array and iterate over it

In componeng class:

```
 this.allfathersDetails = this.jsonObject.map( item => item.fatherDetails).flat();
```

In a template:

```
 <div *ngFor="let details of allfathersDetails">
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there any option without creating a variable?

Comment: You can try to use <div *ngFor="let details of jsonObject.map( item => item.fatherDetails).flat()"> but may be bad for perfomance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
<div *ngFor = "let object of jsonObject">
<div *ngFor ="let father of object.fatherDetails>
<span>{{father.name}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah. It works with <div>. But, I'm working with <mat-select> and <mat-option>.

Comment: You can write first ngFor in mat-select and second ngFor in mat-option.If it works than please upvote.

Comment: Dude, it's displaying multiple select boxes which means it is looping the select and not looping values in select box.

Comment: You can store fatherdetails array in other array in ts file.

Comment: Yeah. That's how I'm working now presently and trying to avoid using extra variable. Thank you.